# cobertura does not read all test cases

Tags: java, junit, junit4, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

i have encoutered a problem where cobertura report does not cover all test cases, and i could not find a satisfactory answer on internet.

i have a main class:

```java
public class SomeClass {

    public Somereturn method1(){
    //Something doing here
    }

    public Somereturn method2(){
    //Something doing here
    }
    public Somereturn method3(){
    //Something doing here
    }
    public Somereturn method4(){
    //Something doing here
    }
}
```

when I am preparing test case for first or second method cobertura will identify its coverage :

```java
public testclass {

    @Test
    Public void test1mehtod1(){
    // testing  mothod1  for some scenario
    }

    @Test
    Public void test2mehtod1(){
    // testing  mothod1  again for some other scenario
    }

    @Test
    Public void test1mehtod2(){
    // testing  mothod2  some other scenario
    }
}
```

this is identified by cobertura lets say 50 % coverage.

but if I choose last or second last method:

```java
public testclass {
    @Test
    Public void test1mehtod3(){
    // testing  mothod3  for some scenario
    }

    @Test
    Public void test1mehtod4(){
    // testing  mothod4  for some other scenario
    }
}
```

It refused to identify coverage and shows only 0 % Coverage.

if I talk about reality, for one controller class I have covered 100% preparing all test cases. but cobertura only shows 22% coverage . 
I am working on a sprintboot application.

Comment: It would help to answer your question better, if you update your question with actual junit code.

Comment: I cant upload all the code publicly as its a company proprietary code.

Comment: It would be difficult to answer the question without seeing your junits, specially which objects are mapped, which annotations are you using for unit class, etc.

Comment: I mean *mocked in the above comment.